# Javascript syntax highlighting and code assistance between declared tags

Tags: aptana

is there a way to tell Aptana to handle the code between some defined tags as Javascript code?

I use in my own template engine code like this:

`<mytag>
alert('test');
</mytag>`

Would be nice if i could teach Aptana to handle everything between "mytag" as Javascript code.

PS: Would need the same for CSS